# Spectrograms - Am I missing something?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, spectrogram

I have the following signal:

[image]

I'm trying to compute a Spectrogram algorithm, but, don't think I'm doing it right..

I have computed the following:

1) STFT (size 256 with an overlap of 128) 
 2) Computed the logs using: '10 * log10(sqrt(re * re + im + im)

This is the result that I get:

[image]

But when I use `pylab` in Python (for the same signal):
  `x = pl.specgram(signal)`

I get the following result:

[image]

Using the `matplotlib` I get the following:

[image]

Obviously, these are very different results.. I don't know why I'm getting these, I'm new to signal processing and spectrograms. Hope someone can help

EDIT:

Here is the Python code.

```
def wavToSpec(wavefile,log=False,norm=False):
    wavArr,wavParams = wavToArr(wavefile)
    print wavParams
    return  mlab.specgram(wavArr,
            NFFT=256,Fs=wavParams[2],window=mlab.window_hanning,noverlap=128)

p, freqs, bins = wavToSpec("test.wav")
pylab.plot(p);
pylab.show()
```

Comment: That last graph is not a spectrogram...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Please see my updated post.. That's what I use.. mhm, any ideas about whether or not I'm heading in the right direction/

Comment: Do you have the code for the first plot after the waveform? I would have expected a two-dimensional plot, but you show a one dimentional line.